# Sqlldr does not insert complete file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to insert multiple images using `sqlldr`. Everything works fine without any issues but after insertion, when I check the image size it's not  the actual size but lesser than that.

I'm using a table with two columns just to test the working of sqlldr. Table conatins one integer column and one blob(for images).

Control file :

```
load data infile 'path of text file' 
append into table TEST 
fields terminated by "," 
( 
  NAME,IMAGE 
)
```

Data File:

```
1,path of image
```

query i'm using to test length of file:

```
select name,length(image),dbms_lob.getlength(image) 
from test;
```

Size of most of the images are 900 to 1000kb. Size of the file after insert is 29kb. Can someone please help me out in this issue. If the steps that i am following are wrong then `sqlldr` should not work at all but its working. I am unable to figure out where I am doing mistake.

Comment: What is your table structure, what does your control file look like, what does the log say? How are you checking the size, in Oracle and for the original file?

Comment: Please add that information to the question via the edit button, not as comments... with the entire control file, plus an example with the size of a file and the reported size after insert, so the two can be compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `sqlldr` that the second column is in fact a filename not the actual data:

```
load data infile 'path of text file' 
append into table TEST 
fields terminated by "," 
(
  name,
  input_file FILLER, 
  image LOBFILE(input_file) TERMINATED BY EOF
)
```

Note the line `input_file FILLER,` which defines a placeholder for the second column in your input file. The expression `image LOBFILE(input_file)` then puts the file contents into the column `image`

For more details see the [SQL*Loader manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/toc.htm), especially [the example about loading LOB files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_loading.htm#i1007627)